# Regular expression for validating complicated username

Tags: regex

So, the conditions are:

1. At least 1 character, max 20 characters
2. Starts with [a-zA-Z]
3. Contains [a-zA-Z0-9.-]
4. Ends with [a-zA-Z0-9]

My expression is:

```
    ^(?=[a-zA-Z])+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}$
```

It works nicely. However, it doesn't work properly with a username's length. I can enter a thirty-character username and still find a match. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Any particular reason for the requirement not to end with a `.` or `-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]$|^(?=.{2,20}$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: @EvgenyAnatskiy and do you understand it...?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to find complicated regexps a poor choice when wanting to validate a string against multiple rules.  They cause unreadable code that's difficult to maintain.

How about (in pseudocode)

```
.length >= 1 && .length <= 20
&& /^[a-z0-9.-]+$/i
&& /^[a-z]/i
&& /[a-z0-9]$/i
```

i.e. check the length, then check the legal character validity, then check the opening and closing characters, exactly as described in your question text.

You *could* also combine the first two lines so that you're only using regexps:

```
   /^[a-z0-9.-]{1,20}$/i
&& /^[a-z]/i
&& /[a-z0-9]$/i
```

I'd be surprised if this was slower than a one-liner regexp, but it's certainly more readable.

Comment: The point is, according to the task, I need to find one solution entirely with a regular expression and another solution with standard functions.

Comment: @EvgenyAnatskiy why is that a constraint?

Comment: Well, I'm supposed to find several different solutions for username validation. So, I came up only with two ideas for now: regular expression and build-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

If it contains only `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]`, starts with `[a-zA-Z]` and ends with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, it doesn't start with `[-0-9.]` and doesn't end with `[.-]`

```
^(?![-0-9.])[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,20}(?<![.-])$
```

*Note*: Works only in regex flavors, that support negative [lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fO8qG1/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex,

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/19)

Comment: Unfortunately, now it doesn't find one-character username. So, it's not a solution yet.

Comment: how `Starts with [a-zA-Z]`, `Ends with [a-zA-Z0-9]` and `atleast one letter` possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a fairly simple solution:

```
^[a-zA-Z]$|^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$
```

Broken down:

- Either: a single character in the group [a-zA-Z]
- Or: Exactly one character in group [a-zA-Z], up to 18 characters in the group [a-zA-Z0-9.-] and finally 1 character from the group [a-zA-Z0-9].

Matches correctly against the following:

```
Valid
Valid.UserName
Valid1-1UserName
0-Invalid
Invalid.
Invalid-ThisIsTooLong
V
```

Comment: NB: ISTR that `\w` will also match the underscore, which is not in the OP's original list of valid characters

Answer (score 0):

If the string does not start with [a-zA-Z] the regex will fail. The rest is easier to understand.

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,19}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW7wC1/4)